# Firebase Database. Listener to reading

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to attach listener to reading of my object.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (!(childSnap.child("Character").exists()))
        {
            continue;
        }
        Runner runner = childSnap.getValue(Runner.class);//need listener
        int energyCurrent = runner.getEnergyCurrent();
        int energyMax = runner.getEnergyMax();
        int energyObtain = runner.getEnergyObtain();
...
}}
```

After using `getValue(Runner.class)`, I use `get` methods of my object.

The problem is that this `get` methods return `0`, which means object fields are not initialized. I think that the problem is that the object is not yet loaded and its fields have default values.

So I need a listener to check if the object is loaded. Please help!